# How to add @include('') in laravel 5 with in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I want to import deferent include file with in my JavaScript control statement. I used Laravel 5  blade.php formate. I trying deferent ways like below.
{

```
 <script>
 var slide_bar;

           if (slide_bar == 'x') {

                  //first try
                  {{ @include('ex.blade.php')}};

                  //second try
                  line_1=@include('ex.blade.php')
                  document.getElementById("slide_bar").innerHTML = line_1;

                  //3rd way
                  var slide_bar = document.getElementById("slide_bar");
                  slide_bar.appendChild({{@include('ex.blade.php')}});

            } else if (slide_bar == 'y') {
              //code

            } else if (slide_bar == 'z') {
               //code
            } else {
               //code
            }

        </script>
```

}

please , help me.How can I use @include('') with in javascript ? above every time passed syntax error.

Comment: have u try this {!! @include('ex.blade.php')!!}; instead of {{ @include('ex.blade.php')}};

Comment: still syntax error. i check compile file , give error in this line     ` if (slide_bar == 'x') {
                     <?php echo <?php echo $__env->make('ex', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>; ?> `

         
                }

Comment: have u check ur filename because ex.blade.php is wrong it should be (ex) don't include the extension when using @include() in laravel correct way @include(ex)

Comment: thank you..  @Grald but still error is same.ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  . i use firstway and put '{!! @include('ex')!!};'  , but given same error. if i do any wrong write php code within javascript ?

Comment: you must add a token in your form or page

Comment: ya..thank @Grald your help. i am new to this subject . i don't know about token. i will read it and try.